# Wordpress redirection on already added post type

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a post type News I am adding post under it and it is generating URLs like

```
http://www.example.com/news/article1
http://www.example.com/news/article2
```

Now I want to add rewrite rule like following

```
http://www.example.com/news/(.*)-(.*) and want to get variables associated.
```

Is there a way to achieve this.

```
http://www.example.com/news/audi-a4
```

I will not add it as an post and want to get following variable and redirect to some other page

```
make : audi
model : a4
page-template : new-template.php
```

Please suggest